# Is it illegal or unethical for a supervisor to ask a contracted employee for a large loan?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

I have a coworker who is contracted by a travel agency to my company. My supervisor asked if she could loan her $5,000, and then again for $3,000, and then again for $2,000. This isn’t the first time that I’ve heard of her asking people for money. I went to HR about it, but I want to know if it’s actually unethical or illegal.

Comment: Why are you going to HR if you are not involved? This is between your supervisor and the other employee. The ethics depend on more specifics than you've provided. Asking someone to borrow money or to lend someone money is not inherently unethical.

Comment: @Brandin the supervisor is in a position of authority, and as such this can be considered undue coercion - the employee being approached for a loan may not be in a position to refuse, especially from a superior who can threaten their continued employment.  This is a potentially abusive relationship and as such should certainly be reported to HR.

Comment: @Moo Of course, there is potential for abuse. But that doesn't mean abuse of power has occurred. The fact that the OP is asking about someone else and some other supervisor without any context is suspicious. If the context was clarified (e.g. "the employee feels pressured and asked me what I should do") it would be much clearer. But without any of that context this is just pure speculation; maybe it is unethical, or maybe it is completely ethical but unusual (e.g. borrowing a few dollars is ordinary, whereas a thousand is non-typical but still not necessarily a huge amount).

Comment: @Brandin when in doubt, always involve a third party.  We have the luxury of speculation, as we never ever have all the facts in these sort of social-situation based stack exchanges, so the argument that this is speculation isn't really a strong one against the point.  A supervisor asking a subbordinate for a cash loan screams abusive to me and informing a third party of the relationship is a good thing to do here.

Comment: Also the fact that the loans are recurring is relevant and needs clarification. "She asked if she could loan her $5,000, and then again for $3,000, and then again for $2,000" - Does this mean the supervisor is pestering her employee and harassing her for money? Or does it mean that they have preivously agreed to multiple loans and that this borrowing of money has become an accepted behaviour among these two employees, as strange as that may appear to an outside observer?

Comment: Welcome new user.   (1) it's totally, completely, bizarre  (2) I'm not sure if it's your business but (3) you should alert HR or management *and that's it*.  Something really weird/bad could be going on so you should alert the company.

Comment: @Brandin, while I agree that (1) "the question is just weird and suspicious", we can only discuss questions "on face value".  The simple fact is, taking the bald facts, (2) at any workplace, if you heard of something this totally bizarre happening, you should instantly inform HR/Management - and leave it to them.

Comment: @Fattie The OP already went to HR and informed them, so that's not the question. The question seems to ask about ethics but there is no context at all. So it's still very unclear how to answer this question. Or it could just be opinion based and arbitrary, e.g. "lending 10 dollars is OK, but $2,000 is not," and so on.

Comment: @Brandin - right, gotchya.  (Clearly, the question was too long for me to read  :)  )

Comment: Whether it's unethical to be borrowing money, isn't the main issue, as far as I can see. The issue I think, is why is this person wanting this money. I think the supervisor has got herself into some kind of serious financial trouble, which likely will become trouble for the company.

Comment: The company should be watching this employee very carefully, and being particularly vigilant for any unusual financial transactions/purchases from company expense accounts etc.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere A supervisor borrowing thousands of dollars from junior employees is very strange,and warrants investigation. The OP has noticed a pattern of behaviour which may become a significant problem for the company, and is doing the responsible thing. People minding their own business, helps illegal/unethical behaviour to persist within a company. Borrowing money from employees may not be illegal, but you have to wonder where else she might be getting money from. Often people with gambling, or drug debts will resort to embezzlement to obtain funds.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It is not always easy for a junior employee or contractor to sort out issues like this with a more senior person. The employee loaning the money also may not be aware that this supervisor has done this to others.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The coworker who loaned the money may not have been aware that the supervisor had done the same thing to other contractors/employees. The OP may have been the only one aware of this pattern of behaviour. Ordinarily I would agree  that it's not the OP's business, but the sums of money involved aren't small. I think it warrants a more official investigation.

Answer (score 10):

There are Several things to be concerned about:

> This isn’t the first time that I’ve heard of her asking people for
>   money.

This means they are having continuing money problems. Management might be concerned about how this is impacting her performance at work. This is a warning sign for management.

> My supervisor asked if she could loan her $5,000, and then again for
>   $3,000, and then again for $2,000.

Asking somebody you have power over if they can loan you money is using a supervisory position to get a benefit. This should worry management becasue it may mean that this power is being abused in other ways.

In the first case your concern isn't about is it unethical or illegal. The concern is that money problems is a warning sign to management for an insider threat. If the supervisor was getting loans from payday lenders, or owed high gambling debts, or had unexplained money problems the company would want to know.

The second case is also concerning to the company becasue it puts them at risk. If an employee reports that they felt threatened or if there was retaliation then they can get dragged into a complaint. They need to get involved. Remember if this has happened before management could have also warned the supervisor to never do this gain. Then they want to know if the supervisor has broken that promise.

Comment: While every company would love to know every potential detail about their workers that may impact their performance IT IS NONE OF THEIR BUSINESS!All we know are two private citizens making legal contracts about one lending money to the other.Everything else is speculation and conjecture.Now you might well be correct but you also might be way off base.There is no evidence in OP's post that any coercion or blackmail takes place.Only potential habitual borrowing and financial problems.There is a power differential but that doesn't automatically mean it's abused or a person is taken advantage of.

Answer (score 1):

The legality of the matter depends on jurisdiction, which you don’t mention. Perhaps the supervisor ought to have asked for a loan from the company, rather than someone over whom she has hire & fire power? Because that latter ***could*** be interpreted as coercion, although I doubt that she would ever be prosecuted.

When it comes to the morality of the thing,  I would certainly remember [Caesar's wife](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Caesar%27s+wife+must+be+above+suspicion),

Answer (score -2):

To answer your questions directly:

Q. Is it illegal?

A. No, it is not against the law to ask people for money. It is also not illegal to offer loans to people.

The second one is a bit more of a grey area. What is ethical depends entirely on the person's own moral compass.  Some people may say this is unacceptable behavior, others may think this is just a favor for a friend, etc.

There is no strict answer here.

There are some professions - lawyers and doctors come to mind - that have clear ethical guidelines and stiff penalties for violating these guidelines, however they do not cover personal loans to co-workers.

Comment: It's not against the law to fire a handgun at a pistol range...except that, if you aim it at someone else, it can become murder.  This could well be illegal.

Answer (score -2):

Why didn't you talk to the coworker about this?
You know nothing about their relationship or why she lent all that money.

Since you feel obliged to insert yourself into their matters it would have been the first step to understand the situation.

**What you described is not illegal or unethical on its own.** 
The supervisor obviously is struggling financially, probably mentally as a result as well.

Though in some jurisdictions it may be argued that this could be a case of abuse of power.
*We can't judge that from what you told us and I won't go into wild speculations so for now I treat her with the assumption of innocent until proven guilty - **downvotes be damned** - 
**I still wait to read a law about this specific portrayal of circumstances depicting illegal activity...*** not to mention, we have no idea where this even takes place, laws depend on the jurisdiction.

You could approach her, offering a helping hand or ear if she needs it.

She however might be embarassed and react negatively which could detrimentally impact your work relation, so be very cautious about getting involved and weigh her personality as well as your previous relationship.

***Since you escalated the situation to HR you'd probably be better off not to involve yourself further.***
If you continue and HR didn't tell(they most likely didn't) the supervisor how they know about her borrowing money from her subordinates she'll assume it was you, which again might impact your work.

Comment: I'm confused by the last sentence.  If OP isn't directly involved in the money lending and HR doesn't tell the supervisor how they know, then how would "she know it was [OP]"?

Comment: @Steve-O the power of deduction (; If she suddenly gets a talk from HR about her borrowing money and at the same time a coworker approaches her about this would make her assume this being the same person getting her into trouble with HR.It might be incorrect (not in OP's case) but still would be her conclusion.I admit "know" is too strong a word...fixed

Comment: Oh I see.  I thought "her" in the upper section was meant to be the co-worker who was being tapped for the loan, but I guess you meant it to be the supervisor.  Confusion resolved, thank you

Comment: It's unethical.  The supervisor is using authority granted her by the company to back her own demands.  It may be illegal.  If the supervisor made any threats or promises, it could be extortion.  There's likely to be grounds for a civil suit.

Comment: @DavidThornley I hinted at possible power abuse.I don't think it's automatically illegal or unethical. It is a murky area and questionable / ill advised behaviour at worst but private people are ethically OK lending each other money.Talking about it at work might be a separate issue though.Despite the power difference lingering in the background it becomes unethical / criminal once a person coerces / blackmails actively. If you can refer us to a law regarding this,I'm happy to add it. Keep in mind, we don't know where OP is. $ is being used in many countries or could be just for reference.

Comment: @DigitalBlade969 I didn't say it was illegal, but that it might well be.  I don't know a lot of the details I'd want to know before being more definite.  I do disagree with your statement that it isn't illegal.

Comment: @DavidThornley we'll need to agree to disagree then because from only what we know I'm fairly confident to say it's not illegal (I'm not a lawyer but OP told us NOTHING that is ILLEGAL in my understanding).Now other information might turn up that changes that but until then I remain with my statement.Also, we still have no clue where this even takes place.Laws vary widely throughout the world, so the point of illegality is a moot point at this stage and frankly on this website anyways.

Answer (score -3):

This is none of your business. But in answer to the question, it is neither illegal or unethical for this to occur if there is no coercion involved.

It's not normally a good practice though since it means an underling has some measure of leverage with a superior. But stay out of it, nothing to do with you.

Comment: It absolutely is unethical, as any employee asked this by a boss is likely to feel under more pressure to say yes, or at least more worried about the consequences of saying “no”, than someone being asked by a peer.

Comment: how can it  not be unethical when someone who can fire you, or extend your contract, or change your rate of pay asks you for a loan?

Comment: @Mawg Because people can have a side business lending money... happens a lot here and benefits both sides. So without context saying there is coercion or anything untoward, it's fine... mentioned that in my answer..

Comment: There will always be some measure of leverage, as the person asking is in a more senior position.

Comment: @user1751825 is anyone reading the answer? I said that.

Comment: Your answer says the leverage is going the other way.

Comment: It may be found to be illegal. Depending on the details, it might be extortion, and it may well leave the company open to a lawsuit.

Comment: @DavidThornley it may be aliens, but I covered extortion in the answer. And it's not illegal to loan someone money. Unsure how you managed to get the company in a lawsuit, so I'll leave that to you... quite an imagination you have.

Comment: @Kilisi If there's any threat, overt or implied, that the employee's job is at risk if the employee doesn't make the loan, it's probably extortion.  It's hard, in a case like this, not to have some sort of implied threat.  By itself, it's likely grounds for a lawsuit, since the supervisor represents the company, and in many places that will violate some labor law or another.  I do have an excellent imagination, but I'm not using it here.

Comment: @DavidThornley once again, I covered that IN THE ANSWER, suggest you read it instead of repeating what I said ad infinitum in different ways.

Comment: funny how people automatically assume illegal activity and unethical behaviour but don't cite a single law that actually prohibits regular joe shmoe lending money to their boss or a supervisor borrowing money from their worker bee.Not that it would matter, we have no clue where this even takes place...Imma saddle my unicorn and ride into the sunset now...